# Process a file when user exits page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my code so far, what I'm trying to do is process the io_up.php file when the user leaves the page. It was also be great if i could pause the page load for 3sec after file is processed.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function setConfirmUnload(on) {
    Window.onbeforeunload = (on) ? unloadMessage : null;
}

function unloadMessage() {

    $.ajax({
       async: true,
       url: "/proc_files/io_up.php",
       success: function(msg){
         alert( "Data Saved.");
       }
     });

}
</script>
```

Comment: So what's the question? Are you sure, your code is working? I guess the old trick of opening a window onunload to do the request is there for a good reason (probably the ajax is aborted when the window/page closes?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the code to synchronous instead of async. Just remember that you are doing to hang the user's browser.

This code will be called when people leave the page, refresh it, click a link, etc. Is that what you really want?

You really should be handling this with sessions on the server and not relying on the client. Browser errors, people putting their computers to sleep, network errors, etc will never fire your processing code.

Comment: How would i initiate file io_up.php to be loaded with sessions?